# Possibility of abuse with aUSD issuance on Mandala [AdvancedEscrow]

Tags: smart-contract

In the [`AdvancedEscrow`](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/hardhat-tutorials/blob/master/advanced-escrow/contracts/AdvancedEscrow.sol) contract, we're essentially dispensing out aUSD tokens as rewards (on Mandala testnet obviously). My question is this: what gives me (either as a deployer of the contract or a general user of my dApp) the permission to suddenly dispense out tokens out of our own free will?

Clearly, I'm not understanding something well, but it seems to me that I could essentially "bypass" a faucet and issue myself any number of aUSD tokens I deem fit, at any time just by slightly tweaking the contract.

That said, what would you also suggest a contract developer that wants to build a protocol to issue out aUSD tokens as yield for using their dApp (as some sort of hypothetical usecase)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `AdvancedEscrow` smart contract is used to automatically release funds added to the smart contract after certain precondition are met. In this case, either when the deadline block is reached or when the initiator of the escrow releases the funds.

So the flow of the smart contract is as follows:

1. Initiator funds the smart contract in a desired token (could be ACA)
2. The initiator initiates the escrow by specifying the beneficiary and the deadline after which the funds should be released automatically by the on-chain scheduler
3. Upon the initiation of the escrow, the smart contract uses the on-chain DEX to swap the token that the initiator sent to the smart contract for aUSD
4. (This step is optional) The beneficiary selects the desired token to be paid out in (could be DOT). If the egress token is not set, the escrow is paid out in aUSD
5. The funds from escrow are released to the beneficiary (either by a call from the initiator or by the on-chain scheduler)

The idea of an escrow is that the funds are held by an impartial party while the beneficiary provides a service to the initiator. For example: You hire a smart contract engineer to build a smart contract for you, but you don't want to send them the funds before they are done and they don't want to start the work, before they see the funds. This way the funds can be seen by the engineer, while they still have to perform the task before getting the funds released to them.

> TLDR: You need to fund the escrow in order to get the aUSD and the
> aUSD is swapped in a DEX with a rate available to anyone. There is no
> infinite generation of aUSD or generation of aUSD at all.

The AdvancedEscrow example is intentionally built in a way that encourages improvement (like: what happens if the service isn't delivered? Should the funds be released back to the initiator or should something else happen?).

As for the suggestion for issuing aUSD as yield for using the dApp, it really depends on the use case. You could however incorporate the on-chain schedule to issue the aUSD to the users. It is currently only available on Mandala network as we will do some further optimisations before releasing them on public networks.